# Change order of svg element when its opacity is 1

Tags: javascript, svg, z-index, opacity

I have some svg elements that can be hidden or shown according to their opacity values. I want elements with opacity=1 be selectable; but some hidden elements which are in front of others, hinder any selection. So,I want to bring an svg element to front when its opacity changes to 1. How can I do that by javascript?

Comment: set the elements you don't want to select as pointer-events:none

Comment: Thanks Robert; it worked.